# Abbreviations with acronym, List Style Alignment

Tags: acronyms, alignment

I found a lot of similar questions, but non could solve my problem. I am creating a list of abbreviations using acronym and I want the list to be aligned to the largest element.

My code looks like this:

```
\usepackage[printonlyused,nohyperlinks]{acronym}
\begin{document}
\input{content/_02_abbreviations.tex}
\end{document}
```

and the abbreviations.tex file looks like this

```
\chapter*{List of Abbreviations}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Abbreviations}
\markboth{List of Abbreviations}{List of Abbreviations} 

\begin{acronym}[TDMA]
    \acro{RE}{reference electrode}
    \acro{SNR}{signal to noise ratio}
    \acro{SP-ICPMS}{single particle inductively coupled plasma mass spectrometry}
    \acro{TEM}{transmission electron microscopy}
    \acro{WE}{working electrode}    
\end{acronym}
```

and in my text I use:

```
blabalbalba \ac{RE} and balablbalba \acp{CE}
```

The elements in the list are aligned, but not the SP-ICPMS, as it is way too long. How can I make the list align to the longest abbreviation?

Here is how it looks like:
[image]

EDIT:
Problem solved by replacing [TDMA] with [SP-ICPMS]

Answer (score 1):

Ok wow! Every time after I post a question here - after hours of research - I find the answer...

The \begin{acronym}[TDMA] I found in another question, and I didn't know what the [TDMA] stands for. Well, it does exactly what I want: it gives the length of the tab. So by putting it to [SP-ICPMS], I solved my problem!